# Tapestry webapp with embedded Jetty

Tags: jetty, tapestry, embedded-jetty

How can I configure a Tapestry5 project to run standalone (via java -jar) with embedded Jetty?

I'm looking for a short "recipe" regarding Tapestry5, Jetty, configuration of servlets/ handlers/ whatever is needed to connect the dots...

I've seen a few dots: [How to Create an Executable War](http://fw-geekycoder.blogspot.com/2010/09/how-to-create-executable-war.html), [Configuring Tapestry (ref Tapestry as servlet filter)](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry5/guide/conf.html)

Edit: I'm thinking about a standalone running webapp due to server circumstances. It doesn't have to be embedded Jetty, but I can't rely on a stable appserver. Still looking for a recipe, though, so I don't spend much time on dead ends...

Also, I'd like for Jenkins (Hudson) to be able to stop and start the server automatically when deploying updates - I don't know if that influences what I can do with Jetty, f.ex.

Comment: You can be a bit more specific about what you're trying to achieve.  You don't have to use an embedded Jetty.  You could simply package an entire Jetty with your app in the appropriate directory and use an installer to put some scripts in the correct spots.

Comment: Thanks for your input - the recipe I posted below seemed to be the simplest way of getting a standalone server up and running, with Jenkins able to restart it.

Comment: Regarding tags, it seems removing the tapestry and embedded-jetty tag and adding a jenkins tag would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some digging, and this is the short recipe I basically ended up following:

1. Start with the Maven Jetty plugin as configured in the pom.xml of the [Tapestry 5 archetype](http://tapestry.apache.org/creating-the-skeleton-application.html)
2. Add the `stopKey` and `stopPort` attribute to Maven Jetty plugin configuration
3. Let [Jenkins CI](http://jenkins-ci.org/) run maven target `jetty:stop` and then `clean install`
4. Let Jenkins run shell script `mvn jetty:run &`

Voila - my Java app is up and running with automatically updated code, without any appserver.

Comment: This is not too elegant or robust, so if anyone has a better, but still simple, recipe for getting up and running with a standalone Java app, with Jenkins, I'll switch the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Well, i believe this is a general "how to run a war question". Assuming you indeed have a war, you can use jetty or winstone to "run" it - see :

http://winstone.sourceforge.net

and

http://www.enavigo.com/2008/08/29/deploying-a-web-application-to-jetty/

In the first case, you can directly do

```
java -jar winstone.jar --warfile=<warfile>
```

Comment: thanks - it might be that using T5 or having Jenkins stopping/starting doesn't complicate anything. I'll try it with my project.

Comment: you're right - the tapestry bit was coincidental. (but Jenkins being able to automatically stop and start was at the core of my question.)

Answer (score 1):

- https://github.com/ccordenier/tapestry5-hotel-booking/
  <-- Check its maven build
- http://tapestry.zones.apache.org:8180/tapestry5-hotel-booking/signin

Comment: Thanks - I already had the skeleton of the demo Tapestry 5 archetype:  http://tapestry.apache.org/creating-the-skeleton-application.html